# How to receive XML data produced by a website(webservice) in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, web-services

Input is a URL like this http://ws.geonames.org/children?geonameId=6255148 and I would like to receive the XML file in a SimpleXMLElement for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as your base point:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.geonames.org/children?geonameId=6255148");
//print_r($xml);

foreach($xml->geoname as $geo)
{
    echo $geo->toponymName . "<br />";
}
?>
```