# How to receive XML data produced by a website in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have been trying Simple XML but I can not navigate through the structure of the file. This is the URL I am trying to parse.
https://ws.brreg.no/lod/data/982463718

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your problem. What does "I can not navigate" mean? "I don't know how to" or "When I run this code XXX happens", or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: for example, this code does not print anything:

$xmlAddress = simplexml_load_file("https://ws.brreg.no/lod/data/982463718");


print $xmlAddress;

Comment: You cant expect use to write a SimpleXml Tutorial for you. [There is examples for it's usage in the PHP Manual](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and [on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=simplexml+tutorial). Please look at these first and when you have any specific problems, ask here.

Comment: This produces warnings, doesnt print:
$xmlAddress = simplexml_load_string("https://ws.brreg.no/lod/data/982463718");  

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/min/sesam4/www/webservice/portal.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: https://ws.brreg.no/lod/data/982463718 in /home/min/sesam4/www/webservice/portal.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in /home/min/sesam4/www/webservice/portal.php on line 31

Comment: Also, please use the [Edit function](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4032157/edit) to provide more details to your question, especially if it needs formatting. In addition, you have already asked a highly similar question with [How to receive XML data produced by a website(webservice) in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975936/how-to-receive-xml-data-produced-by-a-websitewebservice-in-php)

Comment: Can anyone check the URL I'm trying to parse, because I get an error saying "this is not an XML file" Is this true?

Comment: No, it's not true. It loads fine with DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at what you're receiving from that site? Instead of feeding the content directly to simpleXML, capturee it in a variable instead and output that. Perhaps you've been banned from that site for exessive usage, and you're getting a 401-denied error page instead of the XML you're expecting:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://ws.brreg.no/lod/data/982463718');
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($content), '</pre>';
```